# Error was: No module named sqlite3.db.base when trying to set up a server in Django

Tags: python, django

Hi thanks in advance for your help.  I'm just getting started learning Python and Django and have been trying to set up the tutorial in djangoproject.com.  I've been trying to set up a server but keep getting this error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x108826090>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 91, in inner_run
self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 266, in validate
num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 23, in get_validation_errors
from django.db import models, connection
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 92, in __getitem__
backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 44, in load_backend
raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.db.sqlite3.db' isn't an available database backend.
Try using django.db.backends.XXX, where XXX is one of:
'dummy', 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named sqlite3.db.base
```

I've tried to locate the sqlite3.db.base using spotlight, but can't find that module.  When I go to terminal and import sys and import sqlite3, i dont get any errors. Sys.path in terminal gives me:

```
['', 
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg', 
'/Library/Python/2.7/site- packages/distribute-0.6.27-py2.7.egg',   
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose-1.1.2-py2.7.egg', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', 
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', 
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info']
```

Currently my settings.py are set to:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.sqlite3.db', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have mangled the `ENGINE` setting. It should be `django.db.backends.sqlite3`.

Answer (score 1):

That's not about importing. You have mistyped in ENGINE settings. It must be like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.                                                              
        'NAME': join(CURRENT_DIR, 'db/cms.db'), # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.                                                                              
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.                                                                                                         
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.                                                                                                         
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.                                                                      
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.                                                                        
    }
}
```

Comment: hey folex thanks for the quick response when i change the settings with that ENGINE and NAME setting i get an error name 'join' is not defined?

Comment: Oh, you should change db name to something appropriate.

Comment: Oh, I see.
'NAME': is the path to database file.